# Page transition animation similar to Medium.com

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, animation

I'm trying to find out how does medium do the animation when you click the bottom button to load the next article.

To see it, please head over to a [Medium article](https://medium.com/on-publishing/3895f4d045d2), scroll to bottom and click to go to the next article.

I know how to use AJAX to load another page, but how can I use a similar animation ? I've searched through their code, but couldn't find it.

Comment: Looks like they use the history API - loading content with ajax and then manipulating the url whithout loading a whole new page.

Comment: Yes, that's what they're doing and I specified that I know how to do that. I just don't know how is that animation working.

Comment: My guess would be CSS animation, but you should follow the Event Listeners tab for that link (it's not really a button, only a DIV) in Chrome Dev tools, to get the specific animation (if you're lucky) or code that takes care of the animation. The event labeled 'click' there - should lead the way. Right click 'Read next' and choose 'inspect element'. Then go to the `Event Listeners` tab on the right and dig in.

Comment: I don't how to use the Dev Tools to do that. I've tried it, but to no avail.

Comment: @AlexDumitru My point was they are _not_ just loading a page with ajax. This thing only works so smooth because they preload content on mouseover. Without the history api it would be horrible for UX and SEO. The animation itself (just guessing): transition of opacity and scaling. You might can do it with something like jQueryUI effects: [slide](http://api.jqueryui.com/slide-effect/) combined with [puff](http://api.jqueryui.com/puff-effect/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is similar to jquery pop effect

http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/dist/demos/widgets/transitions/

try pop effect on page.

it is just a css transition combination of scale and fade;

Answer (score 2):

You can try to achieve the same effect using combination of css-animations and javascript. As a starting point you can look at **[effeckt.css](http://h5bp.github.io/Effeckt.css/dist/)** it's a collection of css animations. Unfortunately it doesn't contain exact animation, so I've tried to reproduce it in this **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/superhacker/ezX3c/)**

The basic idea is to use two effects `scaleDownFromFront` and `slideFromBottom`:

```
 @keyframes scaleDownFromFront {
   to {
     -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
    -o-transform: scale(0.8);
    transform: scale(0.8);
  }
}


@keyframes slideFromBottom {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(100%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(100%);
    -o-transform: translateY(100%);
    transform: translateY(100%);
  }
}
```